# How can I add lua support to a cocos2d-x cpp project?

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x

I have created a cpp cocos2d-x project following these steps [cocos2d-x wiki](http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_multi-platform_project_in_one_command_line):

1. Install python 2.7
2. Open a command line window
3. Go to your cocos2d-x-2.1.5\tools\project-creator folder
4. Run create_project.py. Usage:

   create_project.py -project YourProjectName -package com.example.PakcageName -language cpp
5. Your project will be created in cocos2d-x-2.1.5\projects

But now I want to add lua support to exist cpp project.What can I do?

PS.I know there is a way I can create a project using visual studio template before cocos2d-x version 2.1.2. I can easily add lua support to a cpp project. How can I do it easily now?

[image: template]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click your solution,add project,add "$(cocos2d-x-home)/scripting/lua/proj.win32/liblua.vcxproj" to your solution.
2. Right click your project->Property->Genernal Property->add new reference,check **liblua**. It's OK.